# elasticsearch Query: Sum + Case Equivalent?

Tags: mysql, sql, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have some data in `elasticsearch`, and I'm finding it difficult to create the query I need to fetch some data.

The data I is organized like so (if I was to display it in `csv` format):

```
campaignid, sellerid, action
A, mike, sell
A, mike, buy
A, mike, buy
A, joe, sell
A, joe, sell
A, joe, sell
B, mike, sell
B, mike, sell
B, mike, sell
B, alice, buy
B, alice, buy
```

I want to get this result set:

```
campaignid, sellerid, sales, buys
A, mike, 1, 2
A, joe, 3, 0
B, mike, 3, 0
B, alice, 0, 2
```

In `SQL`, which I am familiar with, I would write this as:

```
SELECT campaignid, sellerid, SUM(CASE WHEN action='sell' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as sales, SUM(CASE WHEN action='buy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as buys
GROUP BY campaignid, sellerid
```

I am struggling to get the equivalent in elastic search. I have managed to count data by groups using help from [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_aggregations.html).

But I am lost as to how to get the data I want (the sum case when thing). This is what I came up with:

```
GET _search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_campaignid": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "campaignid"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_sellerid": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "sellerid"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone can help write the query I want? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution was to use scripting. First, enable scripting in your `elasticsearch.yaml` file:

```
script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on
```

Then, it is possible to use the `sum` operator over a scripted value. So for example, this would be equivalent to the `sum` of a `case/when` result statement in `sql` (only sum up if the fields value is equal to something, in this example, I want to sum only instances of chrome browser):

```
GET _search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_browser": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "browser"
      },"aggs" : {
        "intraday_return" : { "sum" : { "script" : "doc['browser'].value == 'chrome' ? 1 : 0" } }
    }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer if you only want to take sum of a series of numbers.  However, average will not be accurate because 0 contributes to denominator only.